# Bought new chain. Do I have to remove links?

Tags: chain

I have this bike I got it from wal-mart many years ago. Same as this one on amazon:  [Denali](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FNVBSAM)

The chain rusted. I noticed that it listed the chain on amazon. Chain: KMC Z 51
I bought this [one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000AOA3PS).

I'm trying to put it on and figure out how it goes through the derailleur I think I figured it out. But it seems too big. Maybe I just didn't put it on right.

Do I need to resize the chain to fit my bike? Are they standard sizes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chains normally come with more links than you need, and you should use a chain tool to remove the excess links from the chain prior to installing it.

This [link](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-length-sizing) from park tool shows you how to size a chain (but the easiest way is normally to just match the length to your old chain provided it was adequately sized and you didn't change anything else). This [link](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/chain-installation-derailleur-bikes) will show you how to install a chain.

Comment: It hard to compare to my old chain, cause it's rusty and kinky. Maybe I'll just count the links.

Comment: Yes count the links

Comment: Even if its rusty and kinked, you can normally straighten it out enough on the ground so you can run your new chain parallel to measure it easily.

Comment: Count links. If the old chain is worn it will be longer than a new chain with the same number of links

Comment: The difference will be small enough that you can compensate for the "pin-drift" and quickly identify the correct number of links. (This is more difficult with half-link chains, which also suck because the plates straighten, lengthening the chain).